# Bad performance with Paint.Style.STROKE and drawText

Tags: android, performance, android-widget

I am facing huge performance issues with my Samsung Galaxy S3 and custom `TextView` component.

I've overridden `onDraw` method:

```
canvas.drawText(getText().toString(), x, y, borderPaint);
canvas.drawText(getText().toString(), x, y, textPaint);
```

The problem is with `borderPaint` using `Paint.Style.STROKE`. If I comment that attribute off, everything works smoothly, but I need it to get border drawn for my `TextView`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why `STROKE` causes problems, but I got the performance good by drawing the texts into `Bitmap` and then drawing that `Bitmap` in `onDraw` method.